# Can zsh RPROMPT disappear when I start typing or after I run a command?

Tags: zsh

I make use of RPROMPT to show me some "extra" info that I don't want to spend PROMPT space on. However, it gets in the way when I want to cut-and-paste from my terminal window into docs, I have to manually delete the RPROMPT cruft.

Is there a way to make zsh delete the RPROMPT when I start typing a command? Or after I hit enter to run the current command?

Comment: [mpy](https://superuser.com/users/195224/mpy) has the best solution, but you can make the RPROMPT disappear when you start typing by left-padding it with spaces to extend to the character position after the prompt.

Comment: @AFH: That's also a neat solution. But calculating the prompt width might be tricky, see for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250457/33390

Comment: @mpy - It's not too difficult if the primary prompt and RPROMPT are of fixed width, though it will be necessary to use `$COLUMNS` to allow for window resizing. I did write some scripting for my `bash` prompt to add a preceding new-line if the previous command didn't leave the cursor in column 1, and I guess similar code could handle prompts of changing length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that *RPROMPT* gets erased after accepting a command line -- *zsh* has an option right for this purpose (excerpt from the *zshoptions* man page):

> **TRANSIENT_RPROMPT**
>                 Remove any right prompt from display when accepting a command line.  This may be useful with terminals  with
>                 other cut/paste methods.

So, do a

```
setopt TRANSIENT_RPROMPT
```

and your copy & paste should work flawlessly.

Comment: This is a prefect answer - it deletes the RPROMPT after the command is run, but shows it until that point. It means my cut-and-pastes work well.